# Real analysis integration

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ defined on $[-2,2]$ by
\[
    f(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
  3x^2 \cos(\tfrac{\pi}{x^2}) + 2\pi \sin(\tfrac{\pi}{x^2}) & x \ne 0 \\
  0 & x = 0.
\end{cases}
\]
Determine
\[
    \int_{[-2,2]} f(x) \ dx.
\]

Comment: I m totaly confused , i cant interigate f(x) when x not zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\frac{d}{dx}(x^3\cos(\pi/x^2))=3x^2\cos(\pi/x^2)+2\pi\sin(\pi/x^2)$, for $x\ne 0$.  Hence, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-2}^2(3x^2\cos(\pi/x^2)+2\pi\sin(\pi/x^2))\,dx&=2\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^2 \frac{d}{dx}(x^3\cos(\pi/x^2))\,dx\\\\
&=2\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left.\left(x^3\cos(\pi/x^2)\right)\right|_{\epsilon}^2\\\\
&=2\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}(8\cos(\pi/4)+\epsilon^3\cos(\pi/\epsilon^2))\\\\
&=8\sqrt 2
\end{align}$$